# How to prove that for the real stable characteristic polynomial $P=\Phi_T$ of a tree $T$, $P_iP_j-PP_{ij}=(\Phi_{T-[v_i,v_j]})^2$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, graph-theory

If $G$ is a labeled graph, the multi-affine characteristic polynomial (which depends on labeling) is defined by

$\Phi_G(x_1,...,x_n)=\det(I_x-A)$, where $I_x$ is the diagonal matrix $diag\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ and $A$ is the adjacency matrix.

Since we can also write $\Phi_G=\det( \sum_{j=1}^n x_jI_j-A)$, where $I_j$ is the matrix which is

$1$ at the $(j,j)$ position and zero elsewhere which are positive semi definite and $A$ is symmetric, $P=\Phi_G$ is real stable.

It follows we must have $\Delta_{ij}(P)=P_iP_j-PP_{ij} \ge 0$ as real valued function.

How does one prove that in the case of a tree $T$, $\Delta_{ij}(\Phi_T)=(\Phi_{T-[v_i,v_j]})^2,$

where $T-[v_i,v_j]$ means the forests given by $T$ with all vertices (include end points) on the unique path from $v_i$ to $v_j$  deleted ?

In case $G$ is not a tree, how to prove $\Phi_G$ is still a perfect square ? How to read off the square root from the graph?

(Added) The fact that $\Delta_{ij}(P)$ is a perfect square holds more generally if we take $A$ to be any Hermitian matrix. In that case $\Phi_A$ is still real stable but $D_{ij}$ may be non real and the matrix identity implies
$\Delta_{ij}(\Phi_A)=|D_{ij}|^2$ so that it is either a square or a sum of two squares of real polynomials. The interpretation of $D_{ij}$ as polynomial of deleted path in the case of tree is less obvious and actually holds in any graph for which there is a unique path from $v_i$ to $v_j$. How can one read off $D_{ij}$ from the graph when there is more than one path ?

Comment: One get a more interesting result if one replace determinant by permanent. If we define $\Psi_G=permanent(I_x-A)$, then for a tree $T$, we have $\Delta_{ij}(\Psi_T)=(-1)^{len([v_i,v_j])} (\Psi_{T-[v_i,v_j]})^2$ where $len([v_i,v_j])$ is the length of the unique path $[v_i,v_j]$.

Comment: For a general graph $G$ and $P=\det(I_x-A_G)$, we still have $\Delta_{ij}(P)=(\sum_{p_{ij} \in [v_i,v_j]} \Phi_{G-p_{ij}}(x))^2$, where $p_{ij}$ range over all simple paths form $v_i$ to $v_j$. Here simple means all vertices along the path are distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ denote the $n\times n$ matrix $I_x-A$. Let $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.
For $I,J\subset [n]$ with the same number of elements, let $D_{I,J}$ denote the determinant of the matrix resulting from $B$ when deleting the rows indexed by the elements of $I$ and the columns indexed by the elements of $J$.

Assuming $i\neq j$, we clearly have $P=D_{\varnothing,\varnothing}$, $P_i=D_{\{i\},\{i\}}$, $P_j=D_{\{j\},\{j\}}$, and $P_{ij}=D_{\{i,j\},\{i,j\}}$.
By the [Dodgson condensation identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgson_condensation),
$$
D_{\{i\},\{i\}}D_{\{j\},\{j\}}-D_{\{i\},\{j\}}D_{\{j\},\{i\}}=
D_{\{i,j\},\{i,j\}}D_{\varnothing,\varnothing}\ .
$$
Since $B$ is symmetric $D_{\{i\},\{j\}}=D_{\{j\},\{i\}}$.
As a result
$$
\Delta_{ij}=(D_{\{i\},\{j\}})^2\ .
$$

In the tree case, the relation between $\Phi_{T-[v_i,v_j]}$ and $D_{\{i\},\{j\}}$ can be worked out using Theorem 1 of my article ["The Grassmann–Berezin calculus and theorems of the matrix-tree type"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196885803001465) in Adv. Appl. Math. 2004. For those without access to the journal, the preprint version is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306396).

Comment: I don't quite understand. For $\Phi_{T-[v_i,v_j]}$, one has to delete all vertices on the unique path between $v_i$ and $v_j$ but your $D_{\{i\},\{j\}}$ only delete one row and one column. Also how does your argument use the fact that $T$ is a tree. It is not true if $T$ is not a tree.

Comment: did you find a mistake in what I wrote?

Comment: Why is $D_{\{i\},\{j\}}=\Phi_{T-[v_i,v_j]}$ ?

Comment: I did not address that. I found the square root for general graphs. Where did you get that the square root for trees is $\Phi_{T-[v_i,v_j]}$? In general, on MO you should give some context and references.

Comment: I updated my answer so you can find how to relate $D$ and $\Phi$.

Comment: Yes. I discover the tree relation first by numerical computation. The graph case look more strange but is actually easier. I can deduce it now from your  $D_{ij}$. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have time to do the computation in detail now, but I think using Thm 1 from my paper, this should give $D_{\{i\},\{j\}}=(-1)^{i+j}\Phi_{T-[v_jv_j]}$.

Comment: It's not possible to read off the square root from the graph as it depends on choice of labeling . The tree square root is intrinsic which is the original question,

Comment: I would need more details of the definition of dependence on labelling and intrinsic to understand your comment. If you use my formula for a general simple graph what you get for $\pm D_{\{i\},\{j\}}$ looks pretty intrinsic to me. You have a sum over subforests one component of which must connect $i$ and $j$ (hence the unique path in the tree case). The contribution of such a forest is a product over the other components of sum over vertices $s$ in that component of $x_s$ minus the degree of vertex $s$ in the original graph $G$. This, assuming your definition of $A$ has zeros on the diagonal.

Comment: It seems that it is more interesting to use this result in reverse to give a polynomial time algorithm to find the unique path between two given vertices in a tree. If you have a say 300 vertices tree, it may not be easy to find the path between $v_i$ and $v_j$ but we can evaluate $D_{ij}$ using Gauss elimination. If we then remove all vertices from the tree corresponding to the variables that remain in $D_{ij}$, one get the unique path.